# How to prevent multiple dialog box in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I am opening some message boxes with electron's `dialog.showMessageBox`.

But it is currently opening multiple boxes. I would like to open only one message box at a time.

```
fetch(payload.url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    download(BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), data.presigned_url, {
      saveAs: true,
      // openFolderWhenDone: true,
      showBadge: false,
      filename: payload.filename
    }).then(item => {
      const filePath = item.getSavePath();
      dialog.showMessageBox(
        BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(),
        {
          type: 'info',
          title: 'Download Status',
          message: 'Download Complete',
          buttons: ['Close', 'Open Folder', 'Open'],
        },
        dialogId => {
          switch (dialogId) {
            case 0:
              break;
            case 1:
              shell.showItemInFolder(filePath);
              break;
            case 2:
              shell.openItem(filePath);
            default:
              break;
          }
        },
      );
    });
  });
```

For example, I would like to close last message box when a new one opens, OR just not allow opening next message box if one is already open.

Any form help would be appreciated.

Comment: how does the code look like ?

Comment: I added the code. @0.sh according to electron documentation, it seems like I can't programatically close message box.

Comment: why don't you just maintain a flag on your own?

Comment: I wonder how i can turn off the flag when message box is closed. Is it possible to capture modal close event? @pergy

Comment: @emil for any incoming `dialogId` you can be sure that the dialog is getting closed so the flag can be switched in the callback. what do you mean by "modal close event"? If the `X` on dialog, that will call callback, too with `dialogId: 0`

Answer (score 1):

In my project,
I give a state property, for e.g isOpenBrowseFileDialog and use it like a flag. If the dialog is launched, the flag is set to true and it will help to prevent open many dialogs.

```
browseFiles = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const ref = this;
    const { isOpenBrowseFileDialog } = this.state;
    if(isOpenBrowseFileDialog === false) {
      this.setState({
        isOpenBrowseFileDialog: true
      });
      remote.dialog.showOpenDialog({
        properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
      }, async (files) => {
        if (files !== undefined) {
          await ref.handleFilesAfterAdding(files);
        }
        ref.setState({
          isOpenBrowseFileDialog: false
        });
      });
    }
  }
```